# Updating jList causes NullPointerException if the item had been previously selected

Tags: java, jlist

I have `jList` that display `String` values and `jList` can be updated by a press of the button and this works well before a user selects an item in `jList`. When user selects item in a `jList`, the listener `listSelection` `valueChanged` invokes the method

```
public void displayString()
{
    String value =  jList.getSelectedValue();
    // other code using value variable....
}
```

`String value =  jList.getSelectedValue()` correctly assigns selected `String` to a `value`.

The problem is that after some item in`jList` had been selected, pressing update button to update `jList`, for unknown reason also method `displayString()` with code `String value = jList.getSelectedValue()` is also invoked and null is assigned to a `value` despite that pressing of the update button should not invoke that method. Because of that further code in that method gives NullPointerException since `value` points now to null. I cant figure out why `displayString()`  method gets invoked when updating `jList`. Im using NetBeans Swing components.

Comment: Will be much better if you show all code and mark the like from with NPE is throwing.

Comment: Is it `jList` intialized?

Comment: The [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListSelectionEvent.html) states "`ListSelectionListeners` will generally query the source of the event for the new selected status of each potentially changed row." When you update the list, what guarantees that the selected item wasn't removed, in which case you can get `null` for the selected item?

Comment: Thats correct, but the problem is that pressing update button invokes 'displayString()' method despite that this method is declared to be invoked from only one place, change value listener  'jListForRegServiceValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt)  { displayString();}' when a user selects item in the list. When update button is pressed that action listener should invoke only other method 'updateTheList()'  that updates that 'jList', but for some strange reason 'displayString()' method is also invoked.

Comment: Create a [mcve] of the list, the update button and the registered listeners. Looks to me like correct behavior. Also, use @username to reply in comments.